# How can I url-mask my CDN to look like my own website url

Tags: video-streaming, hosting, cdn

To make videos on my site faster, I use a CDN to host a video.
My problem is that the video links are now showing the CDN I use instead of my own site.

I look at a video of https://www.itemfix.com/v?t=21e0du, they use Cdn77 but the link in the video paper to be: http://cdn.itemfix.com/

I'd like to do the same with my CDN (so I will have the video link as: cdn.MySite.com/myVideo)

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: It's most likely a service provided by the specific CDN you're using, so you'll need to talk to them (or read their docs).

Comment: https://www.cdn77.com/ssl